# Bayesian estimators

Tags: bayesian, estimation

I have a model $f(x|\theta)$ ($\theta$ is a vector) for which I want to specify a prior $\pi(\theta)$. I only know that $\theta$ is in some interval. There are ways to specify an ignorance prior (Jeffery's, transformation group, reference prior etc.).

Not knowing how to choose, I have simulated $f(x|\theta=\theta_0)$ many times and tried to estimate with each prior candidate, so that I have a distribution $D(\hat{\theta_0}|prior)$. Based on these distributions, I could choose the "optimal prior"  using some criterion (e.g. MSE).

Is it reasonable at all to proceed this way?

Answer (score 8):

No, this does not produce a reasonable answer. For two reasons: (1) there is no such thing as an "optimal" or a "true" prior. Priors reflect your prior beliefs or your prior information about the problem, not a truth about the parameter $\theta_0$ that is behind your data $x$, (2) your simulation is dependent on the simulation parameter $\theta_0$ which is arbitrary, so your "choice" of prior will also depend on $\theta_0$. In addition, your method ends up picking a prior for frequentist properties, rather than conditioning on the observation $x$, another departure from the Bayesian perspective...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with analyzing the frequentist properties of a certain prior.  Some priors clearly do behave better than others in certain situations and if your main goal is to be uninformative then knowing the properties of the prior you choose can be a good thing.

Comment: In principle I agree with the objections, this is why I asked the question in the first place. But the problem is more about how to translate the prior information on prior distribution. For example if I know that the parameter is positive, maybe a scale parameter and lower values are more likely, what should be my distribution?